# Changing the spacing in align environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, amsmath

I want to change the spacing when using `\align`. My current code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

These are defined as:
\begin{align}
&\text{(Identity)} &d(p,q) &= 0\\
&\text{(Positivity)} &d(p,q) &\geq 0\\
&\text{(Symmetry)} &d(p,q) &= d(q,p)\\
&\text{(Triangle Inequality)} &d(p,r) &\leq d(p,q)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

What I get:
[image: What I get]
What I want:
[image: What I want]

Basically, I want the equations to be centered in the page with the descriptions in brackets being more on the left (but not completely on the left).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `alignat` and add the spacing you wish after the longest entry in the left side column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{eqparbox} 

\begin{document}

These are defined as:
\begin{align}
&\text{(Identity)} &d(p,q) &= 0\\
&\text{(Positivity)} &d(p,q) &\geq 0\\
&\text{(Symmetry)} &d(p,q) &= d(q,p)\\
&\text{(Triangle Inequality)} &d(p,r) &\leq d(p,q)
\end{align}

\begin{alignat}{2}
&\text{(Identity)} &d(p,q) &= 0\\
&\text{(Positivity)} &d(p,q) &\geq 0\\
&\text{(Symmetry)} &d(p,q) &= d(q,p)\\
&\text{(Triangle Inequality)} &\qquad d(p,r) &\leq d(p,q)
\end{alignat}

\begin{alignat}{2}
&\llap{\eqmakebox[B][l]{(Identity)}} &d(p,q) &= 0\\
 &\llap{\eqmakebox[B][l]{(Positivity)}} &d(p,q) &\geq 0\\
 &\llap{\eqmakebox[B][l]{(Symmetry)}} &d(p,q) &= d(q,p)\\
 &\llap{\eqmakebox[B][l]{(Triangle Inequality)}} &\qquad d(p,r) &\leq d(p,q)
 \end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also thanks for your answer. However, I did try that one before. But this seems to put the center in between the descriptions in brackets and the equations.

Comment: It's the whole set of equations which is centred, just like with `align` – `alignat` is here only to control the spacing.  What would you like to have, exactly?

Comment: Probably, I expressed myself wrong. I want the equations to be centered in the page (as achieved by the other answer that was given) while in your example, the center is in between the description in brackets and the equations. However, yours is very close. I'll definitely also upvote it as soon, as I have enough reputation.

Comment: I've added a third solution to take this into account. Is it what you want?

Answer (score 2):

I just create another field on the line with the longest comment, and add a phantom of that long comment.  In this case, it means, adding to the last line, `&\phantom{\text{(Triangle Inequality)}}`.

I show afterwards how it is centered (minus the equation numbering)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

These are defined as:
\begin{align}
&\text{(Identity)} &d(p,q) &= 0\\
&\text{(Positivity)} &d(p,q) &\geq 0\\
&\text{(Symmetry)} &d(p,q) &= d(q,p)\\
&\text{(Triangle Inequality)} &d(p,r) &\leq d(p,q)
 &\phantom{\text{(Triangle Inequality)}}
\end{align}
\noindent\hfill x\hfill(x)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Marcel You are welcome.  If this answer **best** satisfies your need (perhaps waiting to see if other answers are offered), consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.  This will tell other readers that the question has an answer and which of the possibly several answers proved most useful to you.